# Unattended-upgrades mail only on error or reboot?

Tags: notification, reboot, unattended-upgrades, mail-notification

I have unattended-upgrades installed on several servers, some version 12, some 14.  I would like to enable MailOnlyOnError for them but would still like to receive email notices when an update requires reboot.

Will I still receive "reboot required" notices with MailOnlyOnError enabled?

Thanks!

Comment: Good question. I have a server with unnattended-upgrades and MailOnlyOnError and my impression is that unfortunately I don't get any info mails if a reboot is required. Would be nice to know if there is an "official" way to make this work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is a solution based on an answer in [this discussion](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1012637&page=3).
The trick is that the request for a reboot is indicated by the presence of the file `/var/run/reboot-required`.

Create a file `/usr/local/sbin/email_update_required` with the content

```
if [ -f /var/run/reboot-required ]; then
    echo "A reboot is required following updates to server `hostname`" | mail -s "Reboot Required" <mail-address>
fi
```

Adjust `<mail-address>` (for example to `root` or your personal email address). Check the permissions and make the file executable.

Put the following line into your root crontab (`sudo crontab -e`)

```
00 08 * * * /usr/local/sbin/email_update_required
```

(It runs the email_update_required script every day at 8 o’clock, adjust as needed.)

I've applied the above method to a Ubuntu 14.04 server with `unattended-upgrades` and `MailOnlyOnError true"`, and it works.

Still, it would be nice to have a more "official" Ubuntu or unattended-upgrades way to get those notification mails. A switch similar to `MailOnlyOnError` would be great.

Comment: Thanks!

The discussion you linked to also points to [this one](http://serverfault.com/questions/92932/how-does-ubuntu-keep-track-of-the-system-restart-required-flag-in-motd/92940#92940) which pointed me at using nagios to monitor /var/run/reboot.  That'll work for us.

Comment: Ah, wasn't aware of that other discussion. Thanks.

Comment: When posting this answer, I had applied the same to a server with unattended updates. In the last unatteded update, linux-image-3.13.0-39-generic was installed. And I got the first reboot-required message, so it works!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Whatsisname and @azimut for the question and the solution. It is 2023 and I am using Ubuntu 22.04. While the solution still works, I have improved upon that script...

```
# To get ADMIN_EMAIL if defined
[ -f ~/.envrc ] && source ~/.envrc
email_address=${ADMIN_EMAIL:-"root@localhost"}

if [ -f /var/run/reboot-required ]; then
    echo "The server `hostname` will be rebooted, unattended, as per the schedule!" \
        | mail -s "Unattended Reboot" $email_address
fi
```

Two points to note from the earlier answer by @azimut...

- The script can be run as a normal user (as `/var/run/reboot-required` can be read by anyone)
- Regarding the cron timing. This should fall between the time the server runs `apt-daily-upgrade` service and the `Automatic-Reboot-Time` defined in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades` file. Otherwise, we will not be notified as the automatic reboot may have occurred already. The timing of `apt-daily-upgrade` service can be seen by running the command (as a normal user... `systemctl status apt-daily-upgrade.timer`). `Automatic-Reboot-Time` is user-defined. The default value is "now" that is usually not recommended when we want to alert ourselves with the upcoming automatic reboot.